# platform.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, angular9, sql-server-2017

I have a class written in Javascript ES2015. When I try to execute nodemon command I always see this error TypeError: Class constructor Platform cannot be invoked without 'new'

The full error is mentioned below during run time error:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oB6W.png][1]

but I got Compile time success
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaRkj.png][1]

Comment: Please add your code or error message as text instead of an image. That way we can help you easier and more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your `app.module.ts` file which contains a reference to `platform` without `new`ing it.